# GWT and ScriptEngineManager

Tags: java, javascript, gwt

I have a problem.
I'm trying to use JavaScript eval function in my GWT app, I have created class that is creating manager

```
ScriptEngineManager mgr = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine engine = mgr.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
```

Using eval like that

```
engine.eval(calculate);
```

And whenever I'm trying to use method with that manager I'm getting errors:

```
No source code is available for type javax.script.ScriptException; did you forget to inherit a required module?
No source code is available for type javax.script.ScriptEngineManager; did you forget to inherit a required module?
No source code is available for type javax.script.ScriptEngine; did you forget to inherit a required module?
```

Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: It sure sounds like if GWT provides that feature at all, it doesn't let you use `ScriptEngine` to do it.

Comment: So maybe are you aware of some eval functions from gwt? I have been looking over google however didnt found anything yet

Comment: In a pinch?  Do it with https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI, which lets you call Javascript normally.  Indeed, there's an example of using `eval` with this syntax [here](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/1.6/FAQ_Client#Help!_I'm_having_problems_with_eval()_in_my_JSNI_method!).

Comment: Just started reading that site, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GWT emulates only a subset of the full JRE, to be used on client-side, and `ScriptEngineManager` is not part of that set. Actually, the whole `javax.*` is not emulated at all. Generally this is due to the absence of any kind of a, say, reflection-counterpart in javascript, and/or thread/concurrency handling.

See [here](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/1.6/RefJreEmulation) for the list of emulated classes.

I don't understand what you are trying to do, but if you need to evaluate a JSON string using the javascript `eval()` function, just use [`JSONParser.parse(String json)`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/json/client/JSONParser.html#parse%28java.lang.String%29), or [`JsonUtils.safeEval(String json)`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/core/client/JsonUtils.html#safeEval%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, have found solution, used JSNI method.